# Variable frequency of an astable

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, frequency, astable, square

I have to make the frequency variable of an square waveform generator built with the help of an astable. I modified a circuit a found on the internet and everything seems good with only one exception: I cannot bring the astable to a low frequency without destroying the signal.

Whenever I raise the resistance of R13 (thinking about it as a potentiometer) to make the frequency lower, the signal waveform is getting worse and I can't figure out why.

[image]

[image]

I really don't have enough experience (I'm student) to make it work between 20-60 kHz without ruining the signal waveform. I thought if I add a variable resistor before the capacitors I can limit the current so the charging time of it, but I don't know why the signal is destroyed at a certain frequency. Do I have any chance to make it work like this or should I just think about another method? Or what should i modifiy to make it work?

Comment: CMOS give much wider ranges due to very low bias current.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4HEm.gif

Comment: Adjust here http://tinyurl.com/yagza4uj  Rmin ~100, Rmax=10M

Comment: I forgot to mention i am not allowed to use mos transistors..only bipolar. And also no integrated circuits.

Comment: Well Q3,4,5 are reversed

Comment: I fixed them now, but doesn't seem to change anything..Q1 and Q2 still work properly.

Comment: Does it require 50% duty cycle? I may have missed that, if you wrote about it.

Comment: Yes..it requiers 50% duty cycle, frequency variable between 20KHz-60KHz and no dc offset.

Comment: using Red or Yellow LED's as 2V Zeners http://tinyurl.com/y83au2k2 with 2Vpp out.  just AC couple output.  You can change my 5V to 9V also.

Comment: Symmetrical rise and fall? Can the output be trapezoidal? If not, how square does it really have to be? Both edges, too? Etc. (It sounds as though there are a lot of specs, since they are coming out very definite from you when asked. But I'd rather not have them dribbled out one at a time as we ask. So the full specs would be nice to have, without having to ask each question. I have very low interest in offering a suggestion if there is a significant chance that yet another spec will kill the idea.)

Comment: The requirements are : 50% duty cycle, variable frequency between 20-60KHZ, variable peak to peak voltage between 0-3.8V with no DC offset. The signal must have symmetrical rise and fall and the square should look similar to the one from my first image..can't be trapezoidal or something like that. Sorry for not mentioning it all earlier.

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: yes, it's a project i have to do for a class.